# How to connect parts of a model to the rig?

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigging, objects, bones

So I have this robot as u can see in the picture below and I know how to make a rig with IK and everything but only did that with 1 object models.
This robot has about 30 base parts and 80 armor pieces(green and red).

I want the pieces of armor to stick to the base parts (leg armor to the leg etc..)to move along with them.

These are solid metal parts so they can't deform at all when rotating the hips, legs, etc.. I have no idea how to start rigging this model and attach the armor pieces to the base parts so any help would be amazing!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways:

If a piece is a stand alone object:
select the object, shift select the rig, enter pose mode, select the relevant bone, press Ctrl P - Bone).
Repeat for all the objects.

If some different pieces are contained in the same object, you can separate them (Press P in edit mode) and use the first method, OR you can use the armature deform: Select the mesh, shift select the rig, press Ctrl P - "With empty groups".

Then in edit mode select all vertices of a piece (use L and Ctrl L for fast selections), select the relevant vertex group and click assign under the vertex groups list.

As soon as some vertices are assigned to one vertex group only, they will move with the relevant bone exactly, undeformed, no matter which is the value of the weight.

[image]

Comment: This already helped a lot, thanks,  one more question tho. When the model is rigged, I'm gonna make a standing up motion BUT with several parts (not base parts, the armor parts) moving to another place, rotating, etc.. on the model during the animation. Is that possible with this method?

Comment: Yes, but this is a rigging issue: you have to create the appropriate bones: i.e. an arm armor bone will be child of the arm bone, so that the armor will move with the arm (animating the arm bone) and then it can move and rotate (animating the arm armor bone). Vertices have to be parented to the arm armor bone.